# React themes not using JQuery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, dashboard

There are a lot of extremely nice admin and dashboard themes around. Most of them build on top of Bootstrap and JQuery. Some of them even provide ready implementations for Angular and React. But it seems that all of them mix JQuery into the react implementations. As far as I can tell this is not a good solution.

So, any arguments for why it is ok to do this mix? Or does anyone know of great dashboard themes that doesn't use JQuery (read pure react implementations)?

Answer (score 1):

Check out rubix admin template, it has jQuery as an option, but you can remove it completely.

https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/rubix-reactjs-powered-admin-template-WB09498FH